# Auto zoom on certain screen resolution only?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my site displaying the contents of an iframe properly (it's a dashboard from [Metabase](http://www.metabase.com) if anyone is familiar with that).

On my large monitor the dashboard shows fine, however on my 13-in laptop some of the numbers are obscured by an arrow. This is only the case in Chrome, as Firefox doesn't have the issue.

When I take the zoom down to 90% everything shows flawlessly on the 13-in resolution, however I don't want my users to have to manually zoom out just to make the page appear properly.

I've used all kinds of zoom, transform, and scale options to get this looking right but whenever I get it working on the small resolution it just breaks on the larger one. And the CSS code doesn't seem to be the same zoom as if you do it manually through Chrome, if that makes sense. It just doesn't work the same way.

I'm not sure what to do except maybe have the screen size auto adjust for a smaller resolution to 90% but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible.

Any ideas for what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different CSS code for different screen resolutions using [@media](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%40media%20css) tags.

You could also try the CSS [`zoom`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/) property on the `html` or `body` tag, but some people don't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it works in practice, but not quite the way I expected. I used the code on both html and body and it definitely changed the zoom, but not in the way a browser zoom works. Very strange. I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: I got it working somewhat with: `@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) { html {transform: scale(.88);}` - There are some other issues but this is a great start. Thanks!